# only the last link is opened webbrowser.open

Tags: python, browser, jupyter-notebook

I am building a project right now, where I linked many browser Links. But only the last Link opens. I copy a bit of the code from my project for you so you can understand

```
if Essengehen_Hamburg == "A" or Essengehen_Hamburg == "Momo Ramen":
        openweb_Momoramen()
elif Essengehen_Hamburg == "B" or Essengehen_Hamburg == "Dulfs Burger": 
        openweb_Dulfsburger()
elif Essengehen_Hamburg == "C" or Essengehen_Hamburg == "Vincent Vegan": 
        openweb_Vincentvegan()
        
        
# Links zu den Resturant Hamburg 

from tkinter import *
import webbrowser

new = 1
url = "https://www.momo-ramen.de"
def openweb_Momoramen():
    webbrowser.open(url,new=new)
    

new = 1
url = "https://dulfsburger.de"
def openweb_Dulfsburger():
    webbrowser.open(url,new=new)
    
    
new = 1
url = "https://vincent-vegan.com"
def openweb_Vincentvegan():
    webbrowser.open(url,new=new)
```

Comment: You are reassigning the three urls to the same key i.e.`url`. So when the logic for calling your browser opening functions are run, `url` is set to the last link. Or is there any code that you haven't posted?

Comment: Thank you for your fast Answer! But what do you mean same key? Do you know how  I can fix it? :(

Comment: From the code you have shown you are setting the 3 URLs to the same variable.. ALso, where is the if condition logic present and called?

Comment: def Essengehen_Hamburg():
    Essengehen_Hamburg = input ("Hamburg bietet dir eine große Auswahl an tollen Restaurants.  \nA. Momo Ramen  \nB. Dulfs Burger   \nC. Vincent Vegan \n   \nDeine Resturantwahl: ")

Comment: that was the if condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
if Essengehen_Hamburg == "A" or Essengehen_Hamburg == "Momo Ramen":
    new = 1
    url = "https://www.momo-ramen.de"
    openweb_Momoramen(url, new)
elif Essengehen_Hamburg == "B" or Essengehen_Hamburg == "Dulfs Burger":
    new = 1
    url = "https://dulfsburger.de"
    openweb_Dulfsburger(url, new)
elif Essengehen_Hamburg == "C" or Essengehen_Hamburg == "Vincent Vegan":
    new = 1
    url = "https://vincent-vegan.com"
    openweb_Vincentvegan(url, new)

# Links zu den Resturant Hamburg 

from tkinter import *
import webbrowser

def openweb_Momoramen(url, new):
    webbrowser.open(url, new=new)

def openweb_Dulfsburger(url, new):
    webbrowser.open(url, new=new)

def openweb_Vincentvegan(url, new):
    webbrowser.open(url, new=new)
```

Comment: Thank you for your Answer! Unfortunately it now shows me a syntax error with Elif